# call php function depending on website section

Tags: php

I have a php website thats more or less like this. PHP noob here.

**Index.php**

```
<? 
include('conexion.php');
include('funciones.php');
?>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_GET["palabra"])) {
      function1($conexion);     
    } elseif (!empty($_GET["letra"])) {
      include('letra.php');
    } elseif (!empty($_POST["buscar"])) {
      include('search.php');
    } else {
      function3($conexion);
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

All functions fuctions and database connections are defined in the included files.

Website uses only a single html file, so all the content is included or called by the functions. Is there a good way for the website to identify which "section"  or content is the user browsing?
So, for example I want a function to run only when the user is using the search page, should I continue to use the REQUEST to identify what the user is doing? Should I insert a variable like $section and then if($section=search){dosomething()} or maybe using the URL? should I use another approach?

Comment: Crate router system

Comment: Why create? I really don't like reinventing the wheel. Look for already existing routers f.e packagist

Comment: Use am existing router, framework,... whatever. Or learn a lot more before trying to build your own system. You need to be lucid on strategies, not just techniques.
Wow, short open tag, what a time!

Comment: Thanks, any system recomended? its the first time I see this.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

*PHP Page*

```
<?php
    switch ($_GET["page"]) {
        case 'login':
            # code blocks
            break;

        case 'student_notes':
            # code blocks
            break;

        default:
            # code blocks
            break;
    }
?>
```

*HTML Page*

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="?page=login">
  <p>
    <label for="studentCount">Kişi Sayısı</label>
    <input type="text" name="studentCount" id="studentCount" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send" />
  </p>
</form>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="?page=student_notes">
  <p>
    <label for="studentCount">Kişi Sayısı</label>
    <input type="text" name="studentCount" id="studentCount" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to know how can my site know what section you are browsing, so it can call the correct functions(). I have been using request to make it, but it might not be optimal, since there exist many ways. So far I can think of: Requests, URLs, and Variables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a little bit confuse about what PHP is and what can do.

PHP will execute in the server, meanwhile HTML execute in the client.  Who define how to serve and what are you using the language.

For example:
The user click on an item in a menu, each link in the menu would send a URL to the server in a way like this:

```
<a href="index.php?page=palabra" >PALABRA</a>
<a href="index.php?page=letra" >LETRA<a>
<a href="index.php?page=buscar" >BUSCAR</a>
```

All those links will open the same page: INDEX.PHP

Is up to yo to define what to do with the $_GET var sent in the URL.

So, in your **index.php** you can defined:

```
<?php
    switch ($_GET["page"]) {
        case 'palabra':
            # code blocks - DO SOMETHING
            break;

        case 'letra':
            # code blocks - SHOW SOMETHING
            break;

        case 'buscar':
            # code blocks - SEARCH SOMETHING
            break;
    }
?>
```

In that way who control what to show, and when are you.
Any way, PHP have some globals that will point the name of the script or the page being serve:

Check out https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php

I will recomend you research a little bit about php and better try to use a framework like cakePHP, Laravel or Simfony for a start. There are many more.